# Windows 8.1 Domain admin account requires run as administrator

Tags: permissions, admin, windows-8.1

I'm logged into a Windows 8.1 machine using domain admin credentials and want to run regsvr32. I receive an access denied error unless I choose Run As Administrator from the context menu. Domain Admins are in the Administrators Group as seen in the Local Users and Groups window. Can someone explain why? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is part of [User Account Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648649.aspx), which was introduced in Vista.

Admin users do not have full admin rights by default, even they have to be granted permissions when appropriate.  It is Microsoft locking down its security model for a "Least Privileged Environment", where a user does not have more permissions than they actually need at any given time.

Have a look at this article:

[The Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 Developer Story: Windows Vista Application Development Requirements for User Account Control (UAC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905330.aspx)

Comment: I found that article very helpful. Thank you.